# Compute volume using isosurface command in matlab?

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry

How to compute volume using isosurface command in MATLAB. I have a grid data xg,yg,zg all size of 90 x 90 x 90 which I am interpolating into xq, yq, zq in size of 250 x 250 x 250
and f has size of (xg,yg,zg) which has some density value for each grid.

```
G=interp3(xg,yg,zg,f,xq,yq,zq,'Cubic');
p1=patch(isosurface(xq,yq,zq,G,1.5)); 
isonormals(xq,yq,zq,G,p1);
```

Now I wanted to know the volume of the object which made by this isosurface command at density 1.5

Answer (score 0):

So, I have a solution, If you think that my solution is wrong then please correct me.

```
divide=100;
b=linspace(-1,1,divide+1);
a=linspace(-1,1,divide);
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(a,a,a); 
for i=1:length(x)
   for j=1:length(y)
      for k=1:length(z)
        G(i,j,k)=rand(1);
      end
   end
end
actvolume=2^3 
spacing=b(2)-b(1);
computedVolu=sum(G(:))*spacing^3 

isovalue=0.5;
p = patch(isosurface(x, y, z, G, isovalue));
isonormals(x,y,z,G, p);
set(p,'FaceColor','b','EdgeColor','none','FaceAlpha',1);
```